Cannot share the board between LED matrix and button in microbitV2 using rust
I am learning embedded rust by trying to recreate microbitV2 library using nrf52833_hal but got stuck.
pub struct LedMatrix {
    col: [Pin<Output<PushPull>>; 5],
    row: [Pin<Output<PushPull>>; 5],
}

pub struct Button {
    pub a: Pin<Input<Floating>>,
    pub b: Pin<Input<Floating>>,
}

pub struct Board {
    port0: p0::Parts,
    port1: p1::Parts,
}

impl Board {
    pub fn init() -> Self {
        let p = hal::pac::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
        Self {
            port0: p0::Parts::new(p.P0),
            port1: p1::Parts::new(p.P1),
        }
    }

    pub fn led_matrix(&self) -> LedMatrix {
        LedMatrix {
            col: [
                self.port0.p0_28.into_push_pull_output(Level::High).degrade(),
                self.port0.p0_11.into_push_pull_output(Level::High).degrade(),
                self.port0.p0_31.into_push_pull_output(Level::High).degrade(),
                self.port1.p1_05.into_push_pull_output(Level::High).degrade(),
                self.port0.p0_30.into_push_pull_output(Level::High).degrade(),
            ],
            row: [
                self.port0.p0_21.into_push_pull_output(Level::Low).degrade(),
                self.port0.p0_22.into_push_pull_output(Level::Low).degrade(),
                self.port0.p0_15.into_push_pull_output(Level::Low).degrade(),
                self.port0.p0_24.into_push_pull_output(Level::Low).degrade(),
                self.port0.p0_19.into_push_pull_output(Level::Low).degrade(),
            ],
        }
    }

    pub fn button(&self) -> Button {
        Button {
            a: self.port0.p0_14.into_floating_input().degrade(),
            b: self.port0.p0_23.into_floating_input().degrade(),
        }
    }
}

but I have this error from clippy
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.port0.p0_28` which is behind a shared reference                                                                                                      ▐
    --> src/lib.rs:28:17                                                                                                                                                                        ▐
     |                                                                                                                                                                                          ▐
 28  | /                 self.port0                                                                                                                                                             ▐
 29  | |                     .p0_28                                                                                                                                                             ▐
     | |__________________________^ move occurs because `self.port0.p0_28` has type `nrf52833_hal::gpio::p0::P0_28<nrf52833_hal::gpio::Disconnected>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait▐
 30  |                       .into_push_pull_output(Level::High)                                                                                                                                ▐
     |                        ---------------------------------- `self.port0.p0_28` moved due to this method call                                                                               ▐
     |                                                                                                                                                                                          ▐
 note: `nrf52833_hal::gpio::p0::P0_28::<MODE>::into_push_pull_output` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `self.port0.p0_28`                                                    ▐
    --> /home/rom/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/nrf-hal-common-0.18.0/src/gpio.rs:887:1

and basically it is error at every self.port.px_xx
My goal is able to
#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let board = Board::init();
    let mut led = board.led_matrix();
    let mut buttons = board.button();

so I ask ChatGPT and it try to solve by replace &self by self
pub fn led_matrix(self) -> LedMatrix {
.
.
.
pub fn button(self) -> Button {

doing this create another problem which board is moved at let mut led = board.led_matrix(); and cannot be used further.
Lastly, I then try
let mut led = Board::init().led_matrix();
let mut buttons = Board::init().button();

No error appear, but buttons seems to hijack the entire board for itself and now led does nothing.
I will be really appreciated for any suggestion. i don't need the full answer just point me the way and I can try learning it myself.
